# Exoplayer 2.17.1 Cannot resolve symbol ExoPlayerFacory, ExtractorMediaSource, ExoPlayerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-videoview, exoplayer

I am new to android dev and I am trying to make an app. I want to display a list of videos and the player should be able to play any video they want. I figured by the tutorial that exoplayer is the only way to do so.

I have the following dependencies added in the gradle:
[image]

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;

public class MainVideo extends AppCompatActivity {

    SimpleExoPlayerView exoPlayerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
    String videoURL = "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20201217163353/Screenrecorder-2020-12-17-16-32-03-350.mp4";
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        exoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.idExoPlayerVIew);
        try {
    
            BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    
            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
            exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
            Uri videouri = Uri.parse(videoURL);
            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videouri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
            exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
            exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
            exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Error : " + e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting cannot resolve symbol with simple `exoplayerview`, `defaulthttpdataourcefactory`, `exoplayerfactory`, `ExtractorMediaSource`, `SimpleExoPlayerView` etc...

Comment: have you able to fix this issue?